# How to join the same table twice

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'm trying to do is to switch up an id with the corresponding name from another table.

Teams:

```
 1 - team_01 
 2 - team_02
```

Games:

```
 team_a     team_b   score_a   score_b
   1           2        30        40
```

What I want to get is: 
Games:

```
 team_a     team_b   score_a   score_b
 team_01    team_02    30        40
```

I try:

```
    SELECT 
      games.id
    , games.score_team_a
    , games.score_team_b
    , games.time
    , games.category
    , games.team_a
    , games.team_b

    FROM games 

    LEFT JOIN teams t1 ON t1.id = games.team_a
    LEFT JOIN teams t2 ON t2.id = games.team_b
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get team_01 and team_02 from the teams table?  If so you need to do t1.Team1ColumnName in your select. You shouldn't need to join the same table twice. Same with Team 2. t1.Team2ColumnName

Comment: modify the teams table so we can better understand. What are the column names?

Comment: Try referencing the columns in `t1` and `t2` in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  games.id
, games.score_team_a
, games.score_team_b
, games.time
, games.category
, t1.<team_name> as team_a  -- reference the join tables
, t2.<team_name> as team_b

FROM games 

LEFT JOIN teams t1 ON t1.id = games.team_a
LEFT JOIN teams t2 ON t2.id = games.team_b
```

Comment: Dosent work, gave me this :
category: 1
id: 1
score_team_a: 3
score_team_b: 1
team_a: 1
team_b: 2
time: "2019-05-19T21:00:00.000Z"

Comment: check again. if you change `t1.<team_name>` for the proper fieldname, you cant get a number

Comment: It workd... vsc just didnt want to save it. I wasted about 3 houres on this... legit want to die

Comment: good. btw as @forpas said, you probably dont need `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a left join, I don't see why the team ids in the `games` table would not match an id inside the `teams` table.
Also if you need only 4 columns, why do you select all the other columns?

```
   SELECT 
     t1.name team_a,
     t2.name team_b,
     g.score_a,
     g.score_b
   FROM games g
   INNER JOIN teams t1 ON t1.id = g.team_a
   INNER JOIN teams t2 ON t2.id = g.team_b
```